# Regarding xpath parsing of xml with default namespace using Saxon

Tags: java, xml, xpath, namespaces, saxon

I wanted some info related to xpath parsing of default namespace using saxon. I am using the Saxon-HE-9.5.1-3.jar to use xpath 2 features in my code. After including the saxon library in the class path, I am facing a issue parsing xpath for XML documents with default namespaces.

**Sample XML in am using :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RESPONSE  xmlns="http://www.abc.com/" responseCode="200">
  <HEADER>
    <HITS>100</HITS>
  </HEADER>
</RESPONSE>
```

**Valid XPATH: /RESPONSE/HEADER/HITS**

Below are the cases where it works and does not work:

1. **"XPATH Works"** : When no namespace is specified
   Example : `<RESPONSE  responseCode="200">`
2. **"XPATH Works"** : When namespace with prefix is given
   Example : `<RESPONSE  xmlns:res="http://www.abc.com/" responseCode="200">`
3. **"XPATH does not work"** : When default namespace with out prefix is given     Example : `<RESPONSE  xmlns="http://www.abc.com/" responseCode="200">`

Can you please help me out on why saxon treats no namespace and default namespace in a different way ?
Also how do I solve the case of doing xpath for documents with default namespace.

**Below is chunks of my code:**

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathEvaluator;
import net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl;

.
.
.

DocumentBuilder builder;
Document doc;

DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
doc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(b, 0, size));

XPathFactory factory = XPathFactoryImpl.newInstance(XPathConstants.DOM_OBJECT_MODEL);
XPathEvaluator xpathCompiler = (XPathEvaluator) factory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpathCompiler.compile(xpath);
NodeList childNodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Thanks & Regards
Pratap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not Saxon-specific but rather a fundamental part of how namespaces work. In your examples 1 and 2 the `RESPONSE` element is not in a namespace but in case 3 it (and all its descendants) are in the `http://www.abc.com/` namespace. With the `javax.xml.xpath` API you need to define a `NamespaceContext` if you want to be able to match nodes in a specific namespace, or since you're in XPath 2.0 you can use the `*:localName` notation to match all nodes with a given local name regardless of their namespace.

```
/*:RESPONSE/*:HEADER/*:HITS
```

Comment: In my case I get xml from a external source. I can parse all the namespaces and get the URI. But to create a NamespaceContext context from extracted URI, NamespaceContext takes (prefix, uri). Since there is no prefex, whats the prefix to add in the context for default namespace ?

Comment: @Pratap the prefix (or no prefix) used in the original document doesn't matter, you just need to bind _some_ prefix (e.g. `ns`) to the correct namespace and then use that same prefix in your XPath expressions (`/ns:RESPONSE/ns:HEADER/ns:HITS`). XPath doesn't care what prefix the document used, it just matches based on the namespace URI and local name.

Comment: In the case of namespace with prefix like "xmlns:res="http://www.abc.com/", why does the xpath like "/RESPONSE/HEADER/HITS" work even though there is no prefix added to each term of xpath ? In the case for default namespace, I tried adding the default namespace to a namespaceContext with some dummy prefix like "defaultXmlns" and tried the same xpath which worked in the previous case "/RESPONSE/HEADER/HITS", but for default it does not work even though default namespace was added to the namespaceContext. Whats the reason for this ?

Comment: @Pratap in case 2 you're declaring a namespace bound to that prefix, which you could then apply to elements (or attributes) by prefixing their names. The `RESPONSE` element itself is _not_ in a namespace, you'd have to write `<res:RESPONSE xmlns:res="....">` for that.